# jQuery - Check if input field contains one of the words

Tags: jquery, contains

I want to check on click if the input field `#plz-input` contains one of the two words: "red" or "green".

I tried `.contains()` but it does only work with the first word.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if( $("#plz-input").contains('red green')) {
        alert("Wrong Value ...");
    } else {
        alert("Right Value!");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consider a Regular Expression**

You could easily accomplish this with a simple regular expression via the [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function. Just separate your your individual terms with a pipe as seen below :

```
var colors = new RegExp('red|green|purple|...');
```

Then just call the `test()` function, which will indicate if any of those terms are found within your string as seen below:

```
// Define an expression of words to check for
var colors = new RegExp('red|green');
// Check if any of the words is contained within your element
if(colors.test($('#plz-input').val()){
   alert('Wrong Value ...');
} else {
   alert('Right Value!');
}
```

**Example**

```html
<input id='colors' onkeyup='checkForColors(this);' /> <span id='result'></span>
<script>
    var result = document.querySelector('#result');
    function checkForColors(element){
        var colors = new RegExp('red|green');
        result.innerText = colors.test(element.value) ? 'Incorrect!' : 'Correct!';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure? It returns 'Incorrect!' if either red or green are entered within the element, otherwise 'Correct!'. I edited it from using `onkeydown` to `onkeyup` so that may have been what you noticed earlier.

Comment: You're right. It did a booboo until I refreshed. Restoring my upvote :)